# Rails: Check has_many in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

If I have...

```
class Bunny < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :carrots
end
```

...how can I check in the View if `@bunny` has any carrots?  I want to do something like this:

```
<% if @bunny.carrots? %>
  <strong>Yay! Carrots!</strong>
  <% for carrot in @bunny.carrots %>
    You got a <%=h carrot.color %> carrot!<br />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I know `@bunny.carrots?` doesn't work -- what would?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<% if @bunny.carrots.any? %>
  <strong>Yay! Carrots!</strong>
  <% for carrot in @bunny.carrots %>
    You got a <%=h carrot.color %> carrot!<br />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I love RoR but sometimes its simplicity makes it hard to learn... isn't that a contradiction in terms?

Answer (score 3):

```
unless @bunny.carrots.empty?
```

would work as well

Answer (score 1):

either:

```
  if @bunny.carrots.length>0
```

or

```
unless @bunny.carrots.nil? || @bunny.carrots.length>0
```

or

```
  if @bunny.carrots.any?
```

by the way, you will find more operations on collections if you use irb or script/console with require 'irb/completion'

Answer (score 0):

`@bunny.carrots` is an array, so you can treat it as such by calling [array methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html) on it, e.g. `unless @bunny.carrots.empty?`